# How to get UNION table name?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE t1 LIKE testTable
CREATE TABLE t2 LIKE testTable
CREATE TABLE t3 LIKE testTable

CREATE TABLE tableALL LIKE testTable;
ALTER TABLE tableALL ENGINE=MERGE UNION=(t1,t2,t3) INSERT_METHOD=LAST;
```

Can i get a `tableALL` that is the union of t1, t2 and t3 with a SQL query?

Comment: Do you want to create a table named "tableALL" which is union of t1, t2 and t3, or do you want just to select a result set which contains unioned content of t1, t2 and t3?

Comment: @AycanYaşıt i want to get the result

Comment: @Matt What about running SHOW CREATE TABLE tableALL; and then getting UNION=(t1,t2,t3), using a regexp in some programming language like Perl or PHP?

Comment: @AycanYaşıt it seems the only way to get UNION table name,I thought there is a sql query to get it . thank u man

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch table nemes manually while you union them:

```
SELECT *, 't1' AS tableName FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 't2' AS tableName FROM t2
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 't3' AS tableName FROM t3
```